# Routine for improving hip mobility for sumo deadlifts

Tags: strength-training, deadlifts, powerlifting, mobility

I have always deadlifted in a conventional stance and have never had problems with hip mobility with my squat. Recently however, I found that when trying to follow “cues” in the sumo deadlift, such as spreading the floor and opening up, that I am unable to do so and end up mostly doing a “conventional deadlift” with just a wider stance. I can sink a squat ATG in flat shoes but for some reason, I seem unable to properly open my hips to utilize the leverages involved in deadlifting with a sumo stance.

What kind of routines would help me in being able to open up my hips and “drop” to the bar and be able to pull the bar up comfortably, without turning into a more or less conventional deadlift.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing some bodyweight squats with a band between your legs, it will then come natural to use a wider stance.

If your problem is trunk position, then I suggest trying out dumbell deadlifts, light dumbells just to get the feel of the movement or if you have one, use an Hex bar/trap bar.

But if you go to a gym and don't train in your home, I'd suggest just asking someone in person.